# Is Pipeline in gremlin run faster and can save from out of memory errors?

Tags: titan, gremlin

Here is the code snippet without pipeline,

```
map = [:]
edges = g.V('type', 'update').inE('createupdate')
for(edge in edges)
{
        date_long = edge.since.toLong()
        incrValInMap(map,date_long) // this function add\increment value in map
}
```

And Here is one with pipleline doing same thing

```
map = [:]
g.V('type', 'update').inE('createupdate').since.groupCount(map)
```

I have couple of questions

1. Is pipleline a lazy evaluation? mean it does not need all vertex gathered before it moves to next pipe?
2. Is second code snippet will run faster than first one?
3. Is second code snippet will result in less memory consumption

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real difference between your two snippets of code.  Both use a `Pipeline`...the only difference is the way you are building your group count and how you iterate it.  To me, the second code snippet is better as it is easier to read and requires less code.  The `groupCount` step from your second code snippet is doing basically the same thing that your doing manually in your first snippet.